# Log some power statistics (temp., cpu usage, cpu speed etc.). Bash script for cron

Tags: bash, file, logging, battery, measure

I'm looking for some bash script which can log all the stuff possible to be useuful for getting to know what makes my laptop's battery drain so fast.

Pointless to ask what can cause my laptop being so no-power efficent, I've been looking for this for some time now.

So, I think I can find something useful if do measure for:
 - CPU temp.,
 - CPU usage,(average?)
 - CPU current speed, (average?)
 - Battery status,
 - DPM power state (cat /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_state)

There are propably more usefull things to record, but these are ma first shot. Can anyone help me with writing this down as a script resulting with one line per measure log file.

Regards!

Comment: Since you tagged `bash`, I'm going to guess maybe you're running Linux on your laptop. If that's the case, I'd start with `powertop`...

Comment: I did, but it won't help this time - it's not the case.

Comment: If so, you should specify which OS you're running.